# PostgreSQL: How to view current "grant usage on schema" permissions?

Tags: postgresql, database-permissions

Is there a system view in Postgres where I can see which users/roles have "grant usage" and on which schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grants are stored in ACLs (=Access Control Lists) for each schema. You can view them by looking a `pg_namespace`

```
select nspname, nspacl 
from pg_namespace
```

The format of the acl is explained [in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-priv.html#PRIVILEGE-ABBREVS-TABLE)

Comment: Thank you! I noticed now the same is also available with \dn+ Must be selecting from the same place - pg_namespace.

Comment: @XerX: if you start `psql` with the option `--echo-hidden` you can see the queries that it uses to generate that output

Comment: yep:
postgres=> \dn+
********* QUERY **********
SELECT n.nspname AS "Name",
  pg_catalog.pg_get_userbyid(n.nspowner) AS "Owner",
  pg_catalog.array_to_string(n.nspacl, E'\n') AS "Access privileges",
  pg_catalog.obj_description(n.oid, 'pg_namespace') AS "Description"
FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace n
WHERE n.nspname !~ '^pg_' AND n.nspname <> 'information_schema'
ORDER BY 1;